# JW Player: What edition do I need to show ads?

Tags: jwplayer, flash, jwplayer6, vast

I am not sure with what version of JW Player I can serve ads.
When I go to pricing: http://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/ only the Entreprise edition has the Ads feature listed.

Does that mean to serve ads through JW Player you need an Enterprise edition?

Comment: You need the ads / enterprise edition for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

yes !!! it is only available in enterprise edition but you can [contact](http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/) them to provide some key for demo purpose, to check how the ads are working

Contact them @ [Jwplayer contact](http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/) , After you have send your query they will contact you. 
As far as I have experienced, Jwplayer support team is very good. I am sure, you will get help from them

Hope it helps :)